# API to get Facebook ads preview link

Tags: facebook, ads, preview

May I know if there is a way to get ads preview links like below
https://www.facebook.com/ads/experience/confirmation/?experience_id={15 digits numbers}

The API document says below, however, there is 24hr limitation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/previews/

As I know the shared link shown above does no have 24hr limitation. So looking for the way to get the ads preview link.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For the ads object, there's a parameter called *preview_shareable_link*. This returns an URL like `https://fb.me/{xxxxxx}`. It's a shortened URL of `https://www.facebook.com/ads/experience/confirmation/?experience_id={15 digits numbers}`.